# How to solve import org.eclipse.debug?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm new to eclipse plug-in development. And I'm trying to implement ILaunchConfigurationDelegate as described at http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fdebug.htm but I can't import org.eclipse.debug.core package. It reports this error: "The import org.eclipse.debug cannot be resolved".

I'm using eclipse platform 3.8.1 from Ubuntu repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to all the bundles which your plug-in needs to the file `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`. If you double-click the file, Eclipse will open a comfortable editor.

Don't be discouraged by the plethora of options, Eclipse plug-ins are very versatile.

Look for "Dependencies". There should be an "Add..." button. Enter `org.eclipse.debug.core` in the next dialog and Eclipse should set up everything.